# IIS Setup Redirect traffic from webserver to app server

Tags: rewrite, iis-7.5, arr

I have done quite a few setup which involved hosting applications in IIS and configuring them accordingly, but now I have a different situation ...

I have 2 web servers which don't host any applications , those are load balanced by Cisco ace, and we have application servers that are actually hosting core application and have vip's too.

Now my concern is how to route traffic from webserver vip to appserver vip.

Webservers are only being used here to route traffic to app server

If you can give me pointers in IIS, how to achieve this, then I can research more.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

Comment: Thanks Mathias ...Ok got it ... Let me work towards ARR rules